# shasum of a directory in macos

Tags: bash, macos, shell, hash

I'm writing a shell script that uses the `shasum` to check if the contents of a directory have changed.

On Linux and FreeBSD, the `shasum` have the same behavior when I do `shasum <directory>` however, on MacOS the `shasum` give me hashes **for files only**.

**FreeBSD**

```
$ shasum CONTENTS/
7f986e5e5289c59db1bba48df92ffe4707830aaa  CONTENTS/
```

**Linux**

```
$ shasum CONTENTS/
7f986e5e5289c59db1bba48df92ffe4707830aaa  CONTENTS/
```

**MacOS**

```
$ shasum CONTENTS/
shasum: CONTENTS/:
```

How could I calculate the hash of a directory in MacOS?

**TRY 1: Using TAR with pipes**

Tried to use but seems that this tar option doesn't work on MacOS.

```
tar cO CONTENTS/ | shasum
tar: Option -O is not permitted in mode -c
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  -
```

**TRY 2: Using FIND/EXEC**

It was consistent between MacOS and FreeBSD, but Linux returned a weird hash

```
find CONTENTS -type f -exec shasum {} \; | sort -k 2 | shasum
```

*Linux*

```
c2ddb9bc5f543e956f5cdcc76750cb78cc5f26f3
```

*FreeBSD*

```
3ac2a9d4e2fc5d2d2ec3c7f612e680990cc35824
```

*MacOS*

```
3ac2a9d4e2fc5d2d2ec3c7f612e680990cc35824
```

OTHER FINDINGS ON TAR
`tar` would be excellent as it "archives" a folder and then I could `shasum` it, however the order of how `tar` "walk" the folder structure is **not consistent across operating systems**. As some helpers mentioned in the comments that I should use the same version of `tar` in all systems.

Just an example, on system 1 I have this order:

```
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:23 usr/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/f0/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/f0/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/f0/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/f0/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/f1/aaa
```

and on system 2 I have the following order:

```
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:23 usr/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f3/f2/f1/aaa
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/f0/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f2/f1/f0/aaa
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/aaa
drwxr-xr-x  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/f0/
-rw-r--r--  0 root   wheel       0 27 Jul 07:25 usr/f1/f0/aaa
```

From a `tar` standpoint it if all good, but due to the order, the `shasum` produces a different hash.

**CONCLUSION**

`shasum` is consistent among Linux and BSDs to check an individual file hash, but, when it comes to directories the consistency happens only on MacOS and FreeBSD, perhaps due to how files are sorted.

If sorting is enforced using the `find` command, consistency is only obtained in FreeBSD and MacOS, however this method is time prohibitive as it takes a significant amount of time to calculate the hashes for every single file and then the whole structure hash.

Using `tar` to create a temporary file and then doing a `shasum` also found to be inconsistent between Linux and BSDs, perhaps because of difference in the archiving method.

I think the only way forward is to **redesign my solution**.

Comment: You can install `gnu-tar` from Homebrew.

Comment: thats @Rishav, but I don't wan the end user to have the liability to install anything. I need to find a solution that fits Linux, BSDs and MacOS.

Comment: Surely the modification time will change if the directory is modified?

Comment: Try setting your locale to something common on all systems, before sorting:

`export LC_ALL=C && find CONTENTS -type f -exec shasum {} \; | sort -k 2 | shasum`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem some time ago and I ended up tarring the directory and generating a hash from the tar.

```
$ mkdir -p test
$ echo 1 > test/tmp
$ tar cO test/ | md5sum
7b18a99a8ccfef1ebbfd1e7a8b2852ee
$ echo 2 > test/tmp
$ tar cO test/ | md5sum
644042dd530157e604641ea89b4e9152
```

Note that if you write the same content to a file, the `modified` stat is updated and a new hash will be generated for that directory.

```
$ echo 2 > test/tmp
$ tar cO test/ | md5sum
da25819594f123563a837d5786e51950  -
$ echo 2 > test/tmp 
$ tar cO test/ | md5sum
9407b64d43b809a5828a9fc2297b4e9c  -
```

p.s. you should change `md5sum` for `shasum` :-)

**EDIT:**
Discussed it shortly with a friend who uses MacOSX and he came up with:

```
$ mkdir tmp; echo 1 > test/a;
$ tar -cf - tmp/ | md5sum
26c43adc9eca9f63279d08a0d145dd7d  - 
$ echo 2 > test/a
$ tar -cf - tmp/ | md5sum
dc3a68cac0b0224be9b202d86e69c5bd  -
```

Note that MACosx uses `md5` instead of `md5sum`.

Comment: Also note you'll get collisions!

Comment: @Roadowl Collisions? You mean with md5 itself?

Comment: I mean with identical hashes for identical directories. Try it. do `cp -axvp ./test /tmp`. Then perform the md5sum like you do on ./test and on /tmp/test. They will be identical. So the hash you create with tar can not *uniquely* identiify a directory.

Comment: @Roadowl You're right, but this only happens when you copy the directory within the same minute. Tar incorporates the date of files, thus making this less probable.

Comment: It doesnt work consistently across Linux, BSDs and MacOS. But never mind... I will redesign my script. Thanks @Bayou